# On Windows how do I get rubygem swipely/docker-api to connect with local docker daemon (service)

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-api

I have a ruby script running on

ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
all running on a windows 10 pro 64 bit box.

The docker .exe client installed with docker connects properly to

DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375

and connects and runs properly in the same shell running ruby and the script.

The script at present is simply

```
require 'docker'

Docker.url='tcp://localhost:2375' # I also tried http://localhost:2375
# results were the same

Docker.options={}
vers = Docker.version  # this hangs for a very long timeout
```

Docker.version hangs and eventually times out due to a failure to connect to the daemon.  I am stuck writing the script unless I can get it to connect to the local docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the gem or ruby or excon or whatever does not resolve "localhost"

If I use this for the Docker.url

Docker.url='tcp://127.0.0.1:2375'

it works.